# Do I need to repair my tires?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

I hit a curb while trying to make a left turn :( Now I’m not an expert mechanic and this car is relatively new (about 6 months) so I’m here to ask if the tires look bad where I have to get it replaced ASAP or should I wait until I get my next oil change in Dec/Jan to have Honda’s mechanics look it up? I drive about 12 miles to and from school on the highway. I might take it to a nearby repair shop tomorrow but I’m here for second eyes and opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you do. You need to get this fixed now - it is very unsafe.

You have a split in the side wall, which is serious - there are a lot of stresses there. In the UK that would fail.

I'm concerned about your wheel as well - I'd get it checked when you go in for a new tire.

Comment: In fact, I would take it **immediately** to the nearest repair shop. It's outright dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say that tire's a write-off - the upper damage is to the structural part of the side wall and you can see what looks like one of the metal bands through the hole. Honestly I'm surprised/impressed that it's remained inflated.

This is definitely not something that can wait - if you've got a spare I'd be swapping to that and getting a new tire ASAP, you can *maybe* potter a mile or two on slow roads to a tire fitters but I wouldn't be doing anything more than that!